# Implement method of interface at runtime in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, aop

I have a spring data repository for each of my model classes:

```java
interface CatRepository extends MongoRepository<Cat, String> {
    Optional<Cat> findById(String id);
}

interface DogRepository extends MongoRepository<Dog, String> {
    Optional<Dog> findById(String id);
}
```

In the calling code, I often to this:

```java
class CatService {
    Cat retrieveById(String id) {
        return catRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    }
}

class DogService {
    Dog retrieveById(String id) {
        return dogRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow();
    }
}
```

But the logic "methods called retrieveById call the method findById and do .orElseThrow()"

What I want is to write this logic one time.

I thought of doing a "RepositoryHelper" interface :

```java
interface CatRepositoryHelper {
    Cat retrieveById(String id);
}

interface DogRepositoryHelper {
    Dog retrieveById(String id);
}
```

But the implementation of this interface can be deduced, it's always:

*Call the corresponding repository "findById" with the same parameter and apply .orElseThrow() on the result.*

How to have this implementation generated automatically ? I think aspects and proxies can help.

Comment: u know u could just define the return type directly in the Spring Repository interface? like so `interface CatRepository extends MongoRepository<Cat, String> {
    Cat findById(String id);
}`

Comment: I know but on Error this returns null, I want an exception :)

Comment: The `findById` is already on the default methods of the interfaces so you don't need to respecify it. Just don't try to shoehorn AOP in there and generate classes at runtime. Keep it simple and just write the code.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this? I love AOP. In native AspectJ and to some degree also in Spring AOP, you could use ITD + reflection to achieve something like this. But in this case, maybe simple OOP is enough.

Given a simplified version of `MongoRepository`, ...

```java
package org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface MongoRepository<T, ID> {
  Optional<T> findById(ID id);
}
```

... and these entity classes and repository implementions:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

public class Dog {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public class DogRepository implements MongoRepository<Dog, String> {
  @Override
  public Optional<Dog> findById(String id) {
    return Optional.ofNullable(new Dog());
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

public class Cat {}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public class CatRepository implements MongoRepository<Cat, String> {
  @Override
  public Optional<Cat> findById(String id) {
    return Optional.empty();
  }
}
```

You can then structure your services as follows:

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface MyService<T, ID> {
  MongoRepository<T, ID> getRepository();

  default T retrieveById(ID id) {
    System.out.println("Retrieving by ID " + id);
    return getRepository().findById(id).orElseThrow();
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public class MyBaseService<T> implements MyService<T, String> {
  private MongoRepository<T, String> repository;

  public MyBaseService(MongoRepository<T, String> repository) {
    this.repository = repository;
  }

  @Override
  public MongoRepository<T, String> getRepository() {
    return repository;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public class DogService extends MyBaseService<Dog> {
  public DogService(MongoRepository<Dog, String> repository) {
    super(repository);
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public class CatService extends MyBaseService<Cat> {
  public CatService(MongoRepository<Cat, String> repository) {
    super(repository);
  }
}
```

Please note the generic default implementation of `T retrieveById(ID id)`.

With a little driver application like this, ...

```java
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083;

public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    new DogService(new DogRepository()).retrieveById("Lassie");
    new CatService(new CatRepository()).retrieveById("Garfield");
  }
}
```

... the console log looks as follows:

```
Retrieving by ID Lassie
Retrieving by ID Garfield
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value present
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseThrow(Optional.java:377)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083.MyService.retrieveById(MyService.java:10)
    at de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q76644083.Application.main(Application.java:6)
```

Comment: Thanks that solves the problem for findById, all my services would have to extend some base service. I'd be happy to also see a solution that automatically implements an interface on the fly, also because I'm curious of doing like this and also because I'm looking to do more retrieve* function that would call the corresponding find* function and unwrap the Optional. For example DogRepository would have a findByCanineId() and would like to create a retrieveByCanineId() function. Should I create another question or add an "EDIT" to it ?

Comment: Don't you mind reflection to determine classes and methods? I don't want any complaints later that is is not beuatiful.

Comment: Oh yeah I'm totally willing to have reflection. I take the method name "retrieveById", I remove the "retrieve" to have the "ById" and then I prepend "find" to know which method to call :)

Comment: The problem with your question is, that it is unclear due to incomplete example code. If e.g. your services do not inherit a repository member from a generic base service, but each one declares its own repository field manually with different field names and types, it gets really tricky to find them, especially if maybe the same service has multiple repository references. I also do not fully understand what you need the extra repository helper interfaces for.

Comment: An [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would be helpful, otherwise I will guess wrong, and you will complain again that it is not what you need. So please, do your job and publish an MCVE on GitHub, implementing the methods manually for cats and dogs, which you want to be aspect-generated. Do not use any extra interfaces unnecessary for the manual implementation, and please also add code calling the methods in question, so I can see them in action.